# How do I update a document with info for a specific user using an identifier?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose on a nodejs & express server.

Schema:

```
var MatchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  // list of Strings which are their _id in User collection
  players: [String],
  geolocations: {playerId: {lat: Number, lon: Number}},
});
```

My routing

```
router.post('/:id', function(req, res) {
  Match.update(
    {_id: req.params.id},
    {
      $set: {
        `geolocation.${req.body.myPlayerId}`: {
          lat: req.body.lat,
          lon: req.body.lon
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

This will cause a syntax error: `geolocation.${req.body.myPlayerId}` (formatted String in ES6)

I'm fine with using a list of JS Object if that helps me solve this easier. Maybe I could rethink my design to just store the geolocation info in each User document then get all geolocation info and send it to each player when a request is made.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the combination of [findById](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById) and [save](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)?

```
Match.findById(req.params.id, function(err, matchDoc) {

    if (err) throw err;

    matchDoc['geolocations'][${req.body.myPlayerId}] = {lat: req.body.lat, lon: req.body.lon}
    matchDoc.save();
});
```